# MacTeX 2014 TeX Distribution panel broken under Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: lyx, mactex, lyx-layouts

I've installed MacTex-2014 on my Mac running on Yosemite. The Tex Distribution window is broken, and am unable to explore all the templates on the Lyx. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: The fact that the TeX Distribution panel is broken by Yosemite is a known problem, not fixed yet, but a workaround exists. See https://tug.org/mactex/yosemite.html, paragraph "The TeX Dist Preference Pane".

Comment: I just stumbled on this problem myself and it seems there is now also a replacement control panel which is linked in the above article.